# How to solve the unresolve dependency ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.0, 16.0.0)

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

I have problems with dependency. I don't know what when I wrong since I haven't open my project for few weeks. And today I decided to open it to continue with my work but while waiting for it to sync it said that i got problem with dependency.

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.4, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gerobokgo"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.Test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '560003c8-bceb-4896-bf78-435948f4fc6d',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //Layout
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //recylervieer
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    // image slider
    implementation 'com.github.therealshabi:AutoImageFlipper:v1.4.1'

    //image Cropper
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.1.+'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.1.1'

   //FCM SDK
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

    //onesignal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.11.2, 3.99.99]'
}
```

Comment: Facing same issue for 4 days. Any solution?

Comment: enable/disable the connection mode, then you will be fine. I figured it out btw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it!
Just enable the connection mode. Then you will be fine!

Comment: how and where from we can enable/disable this option?